# Access textbox in itemtemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 textboxes and a button in a row, and a Repeater dynamically generates some rows at Page_Load function.

```
<asp:Repeater id="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label CssClass="form-control" disabled="true" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "sid") %></asp:Label></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="quiz1"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="quiz2"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td><asp:Button ID="add" CommandName="add" runat="server" OnClick="addQuiz" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm form-control"/></td>
        </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How do I access the textboxes in the Repeater upon clicking the button in the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `FindControl` on the `RepeaterItem` which is the `NamingContainer` of the TextBoxes. You get it by casting the sender to Button (or Control) and cast it's `NamingContainer` property accordingly:

```
protected void addQuiz(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button) sender;
    var item = (RepeaterItem) btn.NamingContainer;
    var quiz1 = (TextBox) item.FindControl("quiz1");
    var quiz2 = (TextBox) item.FindControl("quiz2");
}
```